# How to make the count of unread message

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In my app i received the message from `GCM.` That messages are displayed  in `groupChat Activity` by using `adapter`. The messages are retrieved from `SQLITE` database by using `userid` and displayed by `adapter` in that activity. Here i need to make the count of unread messages for every user. How to do it thanks in advance

Comment: add field weather the message read or note and do query according to that condition

Comment: how to detect whether the message is readed or not

Comment: thanks dude @askarcali

Comment: if it is your answer accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

Add a field weather the message read or not and do query according to this condition. Update your database once the activity is open and try to get visible list count using listView.getLastVisiblePosition()

```
int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <= listView.getLastVisiblePosition(); i++)
{
    if (listView.getChildAt(i) != null)
    {
        count++;  // saying that view that counts is the one that is not null, 
                  // because sometimes you have partially visible items....
    }
}
```